# how to extract data from a file in java and format it properly

Tags: java

I am trying to extract data from a file and calculate the totals of a persons income. This is what the file looks like exactly:

```
Mark
20
Mike
25
Mary
50
Mink
5
```

The could has to look like this:

```
WHO     TOTAL1  TOTAL2  TOTAL3
Mark     -        -        -
Mike     -        -        -
Mary     -        -        -
Mink     -        -        -
Combined total for Total 3:
Average for Total 3:
```

The "-" lines are where the data will show up when the program calculates it.
If the first total is >10, then the total is multiplied by 10. The 2nd and 3rd is the same but multiplied by 20 and 30 respectively. How can I take the data from the file and calculate it into the format shown above? I wrote out most of the code with 1 calculation to test it out, but it doesn't seem to be working right. I am getting several error messages on this line of code:
**error: illegal start of expression
        public static void calc(double totalOne)**
 This is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Income
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    int i = 0;  
    String name = keyboard.nextLine();
    File file = new File("Income.txt");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("WHO     TOTAL1  TOTAL2  TOTAL3");

    while (input.hasNext())
    {
        String name = input.nextLine();
        i++;
        System.out.println(name);
        double totalOne;
        calc(totalOne);
    }
    input.close();

    public static void calc(double totalOne)
    {
            int money;
            if(input.hasNext())
            {
                input.nextLine();
                int money = input.nextLine;
            }
                if (money > 10)
                System.out.println(money*10);
    }
}
}
```

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: "not working at all"?

Comment: sorry, just added the error message

Comment: In the future, include the whole error stack.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to declare a method inside of a method. Take  public static void calc() {...} block out of the public static void main() method.

Comment: Thanks, just changed it. But now I am getting this error message: error: cannot find symbol
    if(input.hasNext())

Comment: Because your  Scanner input is declared in the main. It has to be a global variable.

Comment: @robguy22, I don't want to be rude or anything but this problem is obviously a hw for a principles of programming level class. I know because I was a TA. And it seems like you have a lot to catch up (you don't have printf's yet, you are missing to close your second scanner etc.). I'm sure your lecture book is full of examples. Take your time and go through those examples first.

Comment: How do I turn it into a global variable? Sorry for being such a nooby lol, I'm a beginner to java >.<

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the number of individuals in the input file is known--instead of a line by line approach, consider taking your input file and manipulating it into a 2D array of integers called `income[][]`, and a String Array `names[]`.

```
names[] = [Mark,Mike,Mary,Mink];
income[][] = { {20,0,0}
               {25,0,0}
               {50,0,0}
               {5,0,0}
```

Assuming you set these up correctly, they will have indexes that match ie. `name[i]` corresponds to the row in `income[i][]`. Using this approach you can  iterate through the respective arrays printing out the correct information on an individual line.

As for the calculations, those can be done using a method that is passed the 2D array and does something along the lines of what follows:

```
while(iterating through income[i][j]){
   if(j = 1){
         income[i][j] = income[i][(income[i][0])*20];
          };
   if(j = 2){
         income[i][j] = income[i][(income[i][0])*30];
          };
```

Having completed that you will then return the newly updated 2D array that has all of the calculations completed. It will be easy enough to print to console or write into a file

```
//using another loop to iterate through the arrays
System.out.println(names[i]+" "+income[i][0]+" "+income[i][1]+" "+income[i][2]);
```